# making a list of all possible random 3 characters or 4 characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I was making a list generator. I tried multiple times and i came with a very long solution which is not perfect. I want a generated list with all possibilities, let's say all 3 characters list which is around 50k possibility 
For example : 
`aaa , aab , aac` until it gets to `zzz` or `999`

Let's say I want to scrape followers from multiple usernames

```
www.website.com/[generated_username]
```

I want to make that generator to create all possibilities for all 3 letters or all 4 letters for me.

so I made a list containing all letters + numbers 
and I made 3 variables  names `timer1` + `timer2` + `timer3`
and that did it for me but it is very slow + very long code

```
timer1 = 0
timer2 = 0
timer3 = 0
target = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
user_ = target[timer3]+target[timer2]+target[timer1]
while True :
    if timer1 == 36 :
        timer1 = 0
        timer2 = timer2+1
    if timer2 == 36 :
        timer1 = 0
        timer2 = 0
        timer3 = timer3+1
    if timer3 == 36 :
        print('done')
    print(user_)
    timer1 += 1
```

I am hoping to get much easier and faster code to generate all 3 or for or even 5 possibilities.

Comment: You could have a look at [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this, setting the amount of repetitions to `3`:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits
from itertools import product

s = ascii_lowercase + digits
#'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'

list(map(''.join, product(s, repeat=3)))
# ['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aad', 'aae', 'aaf', 'aag'...
```

Comment: to get '0123456789' you can use `string.digits`

Comment: this actually wrote all 3 characters even that i dont know how it works lol i am trying t o understand it m thanks alot , btw if i wanted to write all 4 characters i should change repeat = 3 to = 4 right ?

Comment: Yes that's right @kingmajesty Check the linked docs on itertools.product. It performs the cartesian product